# Unity3D Fail to load Dll on UWP [DLLImport] path duplicated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm importing a native DLL (compiled in aarch64 release mode with make) that I import in Unity for ARM64 (Hololens2 with UWP), with the right parameters in the inspector.
On the Hololens, the dll is placed in :
`C:/Data/Users/DefaultAccount/AppData/Local/DevelopmentFiles/Template3DVS.Release_ARM64.immersion/AprilTagARM64.dll`
The Dll fails to load :
`Failed to load 'C:/Data/Users/DefaultAccount/AppData/Local/DevelopmentFiles/Template3DVS.Release_ARM64.immersion/C:/Data/Users/DefaultAccount/AppData/Local/DevelopmentFiles/Template3DVS.Release_ARM64.immersion/AprilTagARM64.dll.dll', expected ARM64 architecture, but was Unknown architecture. You must recompile your plugin for ARM64 architecture.`

As you can see the path to the dll is duplicated, so I presume the dll is not find by Unity... Does anyone has an idea ?

Thank you.